# How to fill NaN values between two values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a `dataframe` like below. I want to fill `NaN` values between two existing values with the value in-between the `NaN` values and not on either side of the existing value.

```py
time_expanded    start_time    end_time    name
10:30:00         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:30:10         10:30:10      10:30:40    11v11
10:30:20         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:30:30         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:30:40         10:30:10      10:30:40    11v11
10:30:50         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:31:00         10:31:00      10:31:20    zonal_game
10:31:10         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:31:20         10:31:00      10:31:20    zonal_game
10:31:30         NaN           NaN         NaN
```

Expected output:

```py
time_expanded    start_time    end_time    name
10:30:00         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:30:10         10:30:10      10:30:40    11v11
10:30:20         10:30:10      10:30:40    11v11
10:30:30         10:30:10      10:30:40    11v11
10:30:40         10:30:10      10:30:40    11v11
10:30:50         NaN           NaN         NaN
10:31:00         10:31:00      10:31:20    zonal_game
10:31:10         10:31:00      10:31:20    zonal_game
10:31:20         10:31:00      10:31:20    zonal_game
10:31:30         NaN           NaN         NaN
```

How can you achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You should try `ffill`

Comment: `ffill` also fills the values between the already existing values and at the end, so it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ffill` but only keep values where `ffill` is equal to `bfill`:

```
df.ffill().where(df.ffill() == df.bfill())

  time_expanded start_time  end_time        name
0      10:30:00        NaN       NaN         NaN
1      10:30:10   10:30:10  10:30:40       11v11
2      10:30:20   10:30:10  10:30:40       11v11
3      10:30:30   10:30:10  10:30:40       11v11
4      10:30:40   10:30:10  10:30:40       11v11
5      10:30:50        NaN       NaN         NaN
6      10:31:00   10:31:00  10:31:20  zonal_game
7      10:31:10   10:31:00  10:31:20  zonal_game
8      10:31:20   10:31:00  10:31:20  zonal_game
9      10:31:30        NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Or the other way around:

```
df.bfill().where(df.ffill() == df.bfill())
```

Comment: +1 very slick, though it will fill the NaN between two consecutive chunks if they have the same value.  E.g. if you replace `"zonal_game"` with `"11v11"`, row `5` will fill in the `name` column

Comment: @Tom Yeah, that's true. It's not very clear from OP whether there will be more than 3 non null values that are the same consecutively and what should be desired output in that case, I'd wait for OP's clarification.

Comment: Very nice +1. OP had a `groupby` in a previous question, so that should help.